# Nine Patch Drawable Being Clipped

Tags: android, drawable

I'm at a bit of a loss with this one, I have a nine patch drawable (See attached) which works in the draw9Patch tool, has no bad patches, works fine on initial loading of the application for ldpi, mdpi, hdpi 1.6 - 2.3.3.

But on each screen size if I go to another activity and then back to the original screen containing the button with the nine patch drawable as it's background, the image is cropped at the top (looks as though it's occurring at the repeatable area).

I've gone through the layout an altered any nine patch drawable used to ensure it's not one rogue nine patch causing the issue with the rest. I've ensured that each density pixel screen has it's own set of resources and I'm about to try moving the xml state selectors for the button into each of the respective drawable folders as well.

The frustrating thing is that even if the nine patches draw incorrectly, rotating the screen seems to fix the problem, it's only when I move from a new activity back to the problem activity, the nine patches clip 50% of the time.

The Drawable is:

[image: Problem Nine Patch]

The left portion of the resulting image is as follows (Notice there is no rounded edge):

[image: Rendered problem nine patch]

If you actually zoom in on the rendered image, it appears to have the top of the nine patch (above the scaled pixel) overlapping the drawable underneath (zoom in and you see the round corner).

The layout for the button has nothing unusual about it:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="@string/some_text"></Button>
```

I can set the layout_height to a fixed height (i.e. 50dp) and this seems to stop the nine patch collapsing on itself / clipping.

If anyone has any ideas at all as to what the problem could be please let me know.

Cheers,
Matt

Solution:

My problem was to do with the following boolean parameters in the state list selector:

android:constantSize="true"
android:dither="false"
android:variablePadding="false"

I'm not sure what caused the behaviour, but I assume it causes some form of caching or some optimisation that introduced this intermittent bug.

Comment: a temporary fix seems to be setting a fixed height or padding that doesn't allow the nine patch to collapse down, but I was under the impression that wrap-content didn't cause this "reducing" behaviour in the nine patch

Comment: How about making the vertical stretching area bigger? It would allow for shorter buttons without totally messing up the gradient. (The clipping is something I would expect, but not its apparent randomness. Any idea about it?)

Comment: I just realised what it was (See the solution appended to the end of the post)

Comment: @GauntFace: Add your solution as an answer plz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was to do with the following boolean parameters in the state list selector:

```
android:constantSize="true" 
android:dither="false" 
android:variablePadding="false"
```

I'm not sure what caused the behaviour, but I assume it causes some form of caching or some optimisation that introduced this intermittent bug.